# Can I represent a Red-black tree as binary leaf tree?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, red-black-tree

I've been playing around with RB tree implementation in Haskell but having difficulty changing it a bit so the data is only placed in the leaves, like in a binary leaf tree:

```
    /+\
   /   \
 /+\    \
/   \    c
a   b
```

The internal nodes would hold other information e.g. size of tree, in addition to the color of the node (like in a normal RB tree but the data is held in the leaves ony). I am also not needed to sort the data being inserted. I use RB only to get a balanced tree as i insert data but I want to keep the order in which data is inserted.

The original code was (from Okasaki book):

```
data Color = R | B
data Tree a = E | T Color (Tree a ) a (Tree a)

insert :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert x s = makeBlack (ins s)
    where ins E = T R E x E
        ins (T color a y b) 
            | x < y = balance color (ins a) y b
            | x == y = T color a y b
            | x > y = balance color a y (ins b)
        makeBlack (T _ a y b) = T B a y b
```

I changed it to: (causing Exception:Non-exhaustive patterns in function ins)

```
data Color = R | B deriving Show
data Tree a = E | Leaf a | T Color Int (Tree a) (Tree a)

insert :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a
insert x s = makeBlack (ins s)
    where 
        ins E = T R 1 (Leaf x) E
        ins (T _ 1 a E) = T R 2 (Leaf x) a
        ins (T color y a b)
            | 0 < y = balance color y (ins a) b
            | 0 == y = T color y a b
            | 0 > y = balance color y a (ins b)
        makeBlack (T _ y a b) = T B y a b
```

The original balance function is:

```
balance B (T R (T R a x b) y c) z d = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance B (T R a x (T R b y c)) z d = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance B a x (T R (T R b y c) z d) = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance B a x (T R b y (T R c z d)) = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance color a x b = T color a x b
```

which i changed a bit as is obvious from my code above.

Thanks in advance for help :)

EDIT: for the kind of representation I'm looking, Chris Okasaki has suggested I use the binary random access list, as described in his book. An alternative would be to simply adapt the code in Data.Set, which is implemented as weight balanced trees.

Comment: Wouldn't you add an `a` element parameter to the already-existing leaf node, `E`?

Comment: The E represents an empty tree, or if used in a node e.g. T Color (Leaf 2) E, means that the node has a left leaf but no right leaf. Maybe the way I'm representing this is not right? thanks

Comment: Why are you using tree at all? If you only want to keep the order of insertion, ordinary list may be the best option.

Comment: the aim is to have an alternative representation of list using tree. this way, search and sort operations can be done in parallel e.g. process each side of the tree using different processors. it is just an experiment to compare the performance.

Comment: re-balance may move other leaves inside. so i think it's not easy to make it...

Comment: @Visham: For your purpose you could still have data in nodes too.

Comment: Yes, I am expecting to have data in the nodes too. But that would be admin info mostly e.g. node color, size of subtree, etc. The main data items will have to be in the leaves. Basically i am looking to have something like a binary leaf tree but have some sort of balancing mechanism when i insert into the tree so i don't end up with an unbalanced tree. I found red-black can be used but it stores the data in internal nodes (external nodes are considered empty and black)

Comment: But why do you want to have the real data in leaves only?

Comment: @svick: i use an example to explain. to represent a mathematical expression e.g. (a+b)/c, you would store the operands in the leaves and operators in the inner nodes as in the diagram above.

Comment: But if want to store an expression, you certainly don't want to do any rebalancing (or only very limited one).

Comment: that was probably not the best example, but there are definitely other uses including what i said earlier. the inner nodes can store admin info such as subtree size, indexes, etc which can improve sort and search operations on large lists represented as trees. i am seeking performance improvement mainly by representing the list as a tree.

Comment: Not an answer, but more an observation:  When programming in a functional language with disciminated union datatypes (ie, the ML/Haskell family), I find 2-3-4 trees much easier to implement and think about than RB trees.  (In an imperative OO language I still think about 2-3-4 trees, but making subclasses for 4 kinds of nodes kind of sucks, so alas I end up implementing as you have above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant `insert :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a`, then your error probably stems from having no clause for `ins (Leaf a)`.

Comment: this is an invariant. there won't be a situation where a leaf will stand alone. it has to be in a tree node (T). ommitting the leaf does not give the non-exhaustive exception. however my problem lies in the other patterns which i am sure is not well formed and not quite sure how to do.

Comment: `Leaf` nodes may always be guarded by `T` constructors, but you recurse into `T` constructors in your last clause. So `ins` eventually has to know what to do with `Leaf` nodes. Add a clause like `ins (Leaf x) = error "dmwit told you so"` and see for yourself.