# Can I insert data unsorted in Red-black tree?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, red-black-tree

While I'm still struggling to find a solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238007/can-i-represent-a-red-black-tree-as-binary-leaf-tree) question, i have another one which maybe is easier. The following is the insert function of Okasaki red-black tree implementation. What I want to do is to keep the data unsorted as i insert into the tree. So the data always go to the leftmost/bottom-most leaf everytime i insert. There is no need to compare for x < y, x > y or x == y. It seems pretty straightforward at first by just removing these guards and only do: ins s@(T color a y b) = balance color (ins a) y b. The behaviour seems to be that the tree is kept balanced but the coloring becomes a bit messed up. And eventually that affects future inserts.. Any idea how this can be achieved? I think this could possibility my first step to my previous question. I just started playing with Haskell, so I am not getting it right straightforward. Thanks a lot.

```
insertSet x s = T B a y b
  where ins E = T R E x E
        ins s@(T color a y b) =
          if x < y then balance color (ins a) y b
          else if x > y then balance color a y (ins b)
          else s

['d','a','s','f']   s
                   /\
                  a  f
                 /
                d        (unsorted tree)
```

Comment: If the data in the tree is unsorted, then the tree isn't a binary search tree anymore. How would you find out if an element is already in the tree (without going through all of them)? If you don't want the data to be sorted, you probably don't want a red black tree.

Comment: Red-black tree is intended for BST but i suppose we can have an unsorted binary tree and here i want to use the same concept of RB tree to keep it balanced.. there should be a way to keep an unsorted binary tree balanced?

Comment: Sure, the tricky thing about balancing is keeping the elements sorted. If you don't care about the ordering of the elements in the tree you can just balance it any way you want.

Comment: I had the same confusion as Cedric, but the question is about implementing a sequence (not necessarily sorted) using a red-black tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use my RBTree implementation in haskellDB, 
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/RBTree

using the `insert` function:

`insert :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> RBTree a -> a -> RBTree a`

feed it a `(\_ _ -> LT)` function, then you can always put new element into left-most place.

Comment: (since I write a lot of docs in the code, they don't show up in the generated html-pages. you can read the source code to get more infomation.)