# How to sort an unsorted binary leaf tree in parallel in haskell?

Tags: sorting, haskell, tree, parallel-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I represent a Red-black tree as binary leaf tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238007/can-i-represent-a-red-black-tree-as-binary-leaf-tree)

The following is just an example of small binary leaf tree with items in the leaves only and they are not sorted. Without flattening the tree, and then sorting it before building a sorted tree again, is there a way to sort it in parallel (using `par` and `seq` primitives). e.g. sort the left and right branches in parallel then do a final sort on these two.

```
       /\
      /  \
     /    \
    /\    /\
   /  \  /  \
   3  1  5  2
```

Comment: Could you clarify: are you trying to do a merge sort, or something more complicated?

Comment: yes, i want to see how to do merge sort on such a structure, then i can add any parallelism afterward. the type def is: `data Tree = Leaf Int | Node (Tree) (Tree)`

Comment: Nom for reopening. This is not the same as the other question from this user, though there is some overlap.

Comment: opened an analagous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299658/no-speedup-with-naive-merge-sort-parallelization-in-haskell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say "without flattening" is meaningless, as the tree has to be deconstructed and reconstructed anyway: Even in your simple example every single node must be changed, so you can't save anything from the existing structure. Read the tree, perform a suitable sorting algorithm (merge sort seems to be a good choice here, especially it works well with parallel computation) and reconstruct the tree. There is no better way.

Comment: thanks. in my case, what i want to do is sort the left branch and right branch in parallel and then do a merge between the two results. so merge sort indeed is best here. for a bigger tree, i may go further down in the tree and sort several subtrees in parallel. but then i still need to do something like: sortList (subTreeToList (subTree))